# Redux isn't holding the data after callback fucntion?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    export const DO_LOGIN = 'do_login'; 
    export function doLogin(values, callback){
        console.log(values);
        const request = axios.post(`http://localhost:80/auth/signIn`, values)
        return{
            type: DO_LOGIN,
            payload: request
        }
    }
```

after calling my function doLogin it is executing the request and `callback` as specified and working good after that the request isn't holding my data anymore and showing it as undefined where I look at in my console?

Comment: `axios.post` is async will return immediately and return a promise

Comment: didn't get you i am getting data but is not assigning to the payload and showing as undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure what you are trying, but I would recommend to additionally use [`redux-thunk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) middleware, to do that:

```
const doLogin = values => dispatch => axios.post(…)
  //not sure if one needs that for axios,
  //but for fetch that is required
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => dispatch({
    type: DO_LOGIN,
    payload: json
   }));
```

That way the action dispatch is actually refered until the request is finished and the resulting data is dispatched to the store.

That way you also handle errors like so:

```
 const doLogin = values => dispatch => … //as above
   //…
   .catch(error => dispatch({
     type: DO_LOGIN_ERROR,
     error: true,
     payload: error
    }))
```

Additionally you can dispatch more actions so indicate the start of the request like so:

```
const doLogin = values => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: DO_LOGIN_START
  });

  return axios.post(…)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => dispatch({
       type: DO_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
       payload: json
     }))
    .catch(err => dispatch(/*as above*/))
}
```

Please note that the action creator returns the promise, so in other places, where you trigger the action you can do:

```
doLogin({…}).then(data => callBack());
```

If you follow that way, it is much easier to in cooperate with [`redux-form`](https://redux-form.com/7.2.1/), if you are using that for your forms, what I would recommend to use, too.

You should be aware, that the within the response object, its data is exposed as stream. That means, you cannot read the data twice. Once `res.json()` or `res.body()` is called, the data of the response is »consumed« and cannot be accessed from the response object again.

Comment: i know how to dispatch the data but the thing is it should also call a callBack function before returning any data to the store